# drawables not in app directory and not adressable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

i recently started the android tutorial from android.com, after downloading and installing Android Studio and the sdk. I made the first app and all, working directory is on a Flashdrive, Android Studio and sdk are on the HDD.

I'm currently stuck at the "Adding action bar buttons" tutorial, as android studio doesnt find "@drawable/ic_action_search".

I understand that it should be in the MyfirstApp/app/src/res/drawable- folders, but those are practically empty (see picture below).

I did find an answer on here that states to simply copy the required drawables from sdk/platforms/android-*/data/res/drawables-*.
Another one states, I can adress "standard" pictures (like the search action icon in my case) by using "@android:drawable/ic_action_search", but that doesnt work at all.

1. Is there a good workaround, easier then putting every icon in every corresponding folder, every time i need one? The [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) doesnt have that, it seems the guy writing the tutorial relied on the icons just being there?
2. (May solve itself with 1.)
   In that other folder, there are many, many drawables, but the one folder I searched (drawable-hdpi) doesnt even have an icon called ic_action_search.png so...where do I usually get that?

Thanks for helping, I'm still hoping this is a common mistake so there's an easy solution here^^

Edit: manually starting the gradle build task doesn't work either, same problem.

([image: Screenshot])

Answer (score 0):

Does your project build? Try running the gradle build task manually.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBCBE.png)

Comment: No, it works for a bit and then stops saying "[...]Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_action_search')." in the Gradle console.